# Setting a PHP cookie value to be intentionally vulnerable

Tags: php, session, cookies, web-applications, session-cookies

First of all, I'm new to PHP and coding in general.

I'm currently creating a web application which is intentionally vulnerable to teach students about web based vulnerabilities. The web app consists of levels with each level containing a different vulnerability.

On the current level, I am trying to set a cookie name "Authenticated" with a value of "0" when a user successfully logs into the level. When they reach the page, they receive a PHP error that they are not authenticated. I want them to be able to intercept the page request, change the value to "1", and then as a result of this changed value, receive a PHP echo containing the password for the next level.

Here is my main page (level6.php):

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location:../level5/login6.php");
 }
 include("authentication.php");
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/wargames.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/script.js"></script>
   <title>Generic Web App Title</title>
   <div id="logodiv"><img src="../images/test.png" width="50%"></div>
   <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Cryptography</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Directory Traversal</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>SQL Injection</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Malicious Redirects</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Burp Suite</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>nmap</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>John the Ripper</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Information Gathering</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Reporting</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</head>
<body background="../images/background.jpg">
<br />
<div id='announcements' style="margin: 0 auto;"><h3 align='center'>Welcome 
to Level 6!</h3></b>
<hr>
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</div>
<br />
<div id="pagefoot">
<div id='footer' align='center'>####
<br />
####
</div>
</div>
</body>
</script>
</html>`
```

And here is the PHP going on in the background (authentication.php):

```
<?php
$error=''; //
$cookie_name="Authenticated";
$cookie_value="0";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);

if($cookie_value = "0") {
    $error = "You are not authorized to view this page!";
}
else {
        if($cookie_value = "1") {
            $error = "Success! The password for the next level is...";
        }
}

?>
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Here is my login code. The user will go to a login page. The login page is basic, and includes this code...

```
<?php
session_start();
$error=''; //
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
        $error = "Username or Password is Invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        //Define $user and $pass
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        //Establish Connection with server by passing server_name, user_id 
and pass as a parameter
        $sqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "");
        //Select Database
        $db = mysqli_select_db($sqli, "");
        //sql query to fetech information of registered user and finds user 
match.
    $query = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=6 AND 
password='$pass' AND username='$user'");

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($rows == 1){
            $_SESSION['user'] = md5($pass);
            header("Location: ../level6/level6.php"); //Redirect to 
protected page
        }
        else
        {
            $error = "Username or Password is Invalid";
        }
        mysqli_close($sqli); //Close Conenction
        }
    }
?>
```

The login code will then authenticate the user and take them to the page above.

Comment: `if($cookie_value ==  "0") {`    use this

Comment: after set the cookie values you check the value of cookie in if condition then i think its always show you You are not authorized to view this page! bcoz you set the value of cookie_value as a 0 , So it Overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i looked at it again, try this:

```
$cookie_name="Authenticated";

// this checks if the value has been set already
 if (!isset($_GET['cookie_value'])) {
// if no value is set, it defaults to 0 and displays the error message
$cookie_value=0;
$error = "You are not authorized to view this page!";
echo $error;



}

// Now here if the value has been set in the url 
else{
    $cookie_value=$_GET['cookie_value'];

        //when 0 ,error
        if($cookie_value ==0) {
            $error = "You are not authorized to view this page!";
            echo $error;
        }
        // and when its 1 success
        elseif ($cookie_value ==1) {

            $error = "Success! The password for the next level is...";
            echo $error;
            }


}

// when a value is confirmed the cookie is then set
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);

?>
```

Comment: Thats perfect, except when I navigate to the page initially, i.e when the users logs in and is taken to this page, they receive an error Undefined index: cookie_value in ..\level6\authentication.php on line 4. If I then assign the value in the URL, this work. Is there a way to fix this issue on the page itself?

Comment: This works great! I did have to get rid of the echo statements however. This is a good fix, although it doesn't work as I intended it to. I can work around this, however just quickly, is there no way to change the cookie value besides in the URL and have this reflected on the page? My attempts using a proxy and a cookie extension in chrome have not worked.

Answer (score 0):

**authentication.php**

```
<?php
$error=''; 

//Here fetch (GET) the data from the database for cookie_value and assign to
//$cookie_value variable.

$cookie_name = "Authenticated";
$cookie_value = $_GET["cookie_value"]; //Here Get The Value of cookie from DB

if( $cookie_name == 'Authenticated' && $cookie_value == "0") {
    // Do what you want if cookie_value is `0`. or set the cookie. or redirect to another page if unauthorized user. 
   //setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    $error = "You are not authorized to view this page!";
}
else {
        if( $cookie_name == 'Authenticated' && $cookie_value == "1") {

            $error = "Success! The password for the next level is...";
        }
}

?>
```

**NOTE:**

- `=` operator Used to just assign the `value`.
- `= =` operator Used to just compares the `values` not `datatype`
- `= = =` operator Used to Compare the `values` as well as `datatype`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have used this and I still have the same problem. If I refresh the page, the GET contains the value "0", which I then change to "1". In the response I receive another value of "0" which I then change to 1, however this doesnt prompt the successful error. Any thoughts?

Comment: One thing..  after set the cookie values you check the value of cookie in if condition then i think its always show you `You are not authorized to view this page!` bcoz you set the value of cookie_value as a `0`.

Comment: No luck, undefined index for cookie name and value error.

Comment: Can You Explain me .. How you get the value of user cookie .. is `1` or `0`

Comment: you have to store the value of `user_status = '0'` default at the time of registration ... understand !!!!

Comment: So basically the whole premise of this exercise is for students to not be able to see a string (the password) while the initial cookie value of 0 is in effect. Students should then change the cookie value to 1 (Through a proxy, developer tools or in the URL) in order to see the string. Ideally I wanted to value to be set to 0 initially so they cannot see the password straight away.

Comment: how can you did with this cookie its not possible man.. i don how you get the value of cookie_value is 1 or 0 .. Just explain me

Comment: Sorry i dont get what actually you trying to do.

Comment: It does not need to be 0 or 1, it could be true or false as well. The value of 0 is set when the user has successfully logged in, and is then redirected to this page. From here, they should see the string "You are not authorized to view this page!" until they change the value to 1 where they will see "Success". I'm creating this as a tutorial on web vulnerabilities. I understand this is unconventional. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: okzz after login  `0` is set but where ??  you store this value where ?

Comment: and how you get this value to your authentication.php page ... and where you check .. just say that.. ??

Comment: I'm not actually sure (still new), ideally I would like this value to be stored client-side so that the user can access and modify it.

Comment: then you have to show me the login page code also first.. for this then i can help u sure..

Comment: update your Question with your login page code.. then i try , @ColbyClayton

Comment: in login page  .. where is `authentication.php` page are located as a redirect ??

Comment: you just did the encrypt the pass as a md5 and store in session and redirect to `level6.php` page  ..

Comment: Authentication is only required for the first time on level6.php, cookies are not set prior to this besides session.

Comment: I only want the Authentication.php code to apply to this one level6.php page.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps happening because you have already set the cookie value =0, no matter how many times you set it, the page will reset it back to 0. it needs to be changed to $cookie_value= $_GET variable